# How to utilize more CPU without threading and processes in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, cpu-usage

I followed a tutorial on neural networks and wrote a backpropagation network using the sigmoid function. My general programing skills are mid-level and i dont really see an option to split the learning process up into parts in order to use threads because the weights change would be hard to implement in a multithreading environment (at least for me). Is there another way with a single thread to utilize more cpu usage like prioritizing or so?

Comment: This task sounds like a task that would benefit a lot from parallelizing, i.e. using multiple processes or threads. Or even using the GPU. Other than that you can try to optimize it. Benchmark which part uses the most time and try to reduce the calls to it and try to write a faster version of it. You could use valgrind callgrind to benchmark it.

Comment: `Is there another way with a single thread to utilize more cpu usage like prioritizing or so?` <- not really. If you can't use more CPU, do less work. Look into optimizing the code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. But its a very low skill code. Its just so much iterations that i thought i could do it in parralel. The only function calls are the call to the sigmoid function. Maybe i could write it inline.

Comment: This part of threading isn't really that hard. Each neuron can keep one "public" output and one "private" output. At each iteration, each neuron reads from the public outputs of its input neurons and stores the result in the private output. This way, all threads can run without synchronization. When all neurons are done, there's a synchronization point where you just copy the private output to the public output on each neuron. This probably doesn't require threading but can be threaded too. When done, you let the threads free to run the next iteration

Comment: Start here https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: There is no magical wand to make a code running faster with no skills. Optimizing programs can be a full-time job requiring highly advanced skills (and a research field on its own). For the parallelization, you can use OpenMP. This kind of use-case should be simple to parallelize. Besides, note that the sigmoid is known to be slow. Also note that there are faster math library than the default one. The Intel one tends to be pretty fast thanks to SIMD instructions (not free for commercial project -- there is no free lunch). I hope you enabled compiler optimizations by the way.